# Python C++ module causing a core dump when accessing the same PyObject* attribute more than once

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, boost-python, python-c-api, python-extensions

So I've finally managed to import the C module into python. However, I'm getting a core dump when I try to access the attribute of an object more than once. Here's the code:

node.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <python3.6m/Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/make_constructor.hpp>
#include <boost/python/detail/api_placeholder.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;
class Node{
public:
    Node(PyObject* attr);
    ~Node();
    PyObject* _attr;
    static int number_of_nodes;
    int _id;
    /*other functions*/
```

node.cpp:

```
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;
//using namespace boost::python;
int Node::number_of_nodes = 0;
Node::Node(PyObject* attr){
    this->_id = number_of_id;
    number_of_nodes++;
    Py_INCREF(attr);
    this->_attr = attr;
}

Node::~Node(){

}
/*there are some other functions*/

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Node){
    class_<Node>("Node", init<PyObject*>())
    .def_readwrite("_id", &Node::_id)
    .def_readwrite("_attr", &Node::_attr)
    .def_readwrite("number_of_nodes", &Node::number_of_nodes)
    /*some other functions*/
}
```

The python file:

```
from Node import *
class Position:
    def __init__(self, i, j ,k):
        self._i = i 
        self._j = j 
        self._k = k
nodes = []
nb = 1000
for i in range(nb):
    nodes.append(Node(Position(i,i,i)))

node = nodes[0]
d = str(node._attr.__dict__)
print(d)
c = str(node._attr)
print(c)
```

output:

```
{'_i': 0, '_j': 0, '_k': 0}
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
// this means segmentation fault
```

I tried looking around but it seems that most of the answers have something to do with multithreading which I am not using in this situation. Is it because of Py_INCREF or Py_DECREF?

Thanks

Comment: In the linked duplicate you should be following the example for `test_2` - you need to create getter/setter functions

Comment: yes, I replaced PyObject* with boost::python::object and it fixed the problem. Thanks!